# Apply CiFilter GaussianBlur

Tags: swift, blur, gaussian, cifilter, ciimage

As the title says I need to implement GaussianBlur to an UIImage; i tried to search for a tutorial but I am not still able to implement it. I tried this

```
var imageToBlur = CIImage(image: coro.logo)
var blurfilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
blurfilter.setValue(imageToBlur, forKey: "inputImage")
blurfilter.setValue(2, forKey: "inputImage")
var resultImage = blurfilter.valueForKey("outputImage") as! CIImage
var blurredImage = UIImage(CIImage: resultImage)
self.immagineCoro.image = blurredImage
```

importing CoreImage framework, but Xcode shows me an error ("NSInvalidArgumentException") at line 5. Can anyone help me to implement gaussianBlur and CIFilter in general?

Edit: thank to you both, but I have an other question; I need to apply blur only to a little part of the image like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've used `inputImage` twice. The second time is probably meant to be `inputRadius`.

Comment: yeah was that! so I realize that I have to study Apple argumentation. One last question: is it possible that opening the view in which I applied the CIFilter the iOS simulator use a large amount of resources (about 60 mb ram, instead 30 which it use previously)?

Answer (score 4):

I just tried your code, and here's the modification I suggest, this works:

```
    let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("th", withExtension: "png")
    let beginImage = CIImage(contentsOfURL: fileURL)
    var blurfilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
    blurfilter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: "inputImage")
    //blurfilter.setValue(2, forKey: "inputImage")
    var resultImage = blurfilter.valueForKey("outputImage") as! CIImage
    var blurredImage = UIImage(CIImage: resultImage)
    self.profileImageView.image = blurredImage
```

So, commenting out the portion you see above, did the trick and I get a blurred image as expected. And I'm using the file path, but this shouldn't make a difference from what you have.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a CIImage greyscale mask image with the shape you want, a blurred CIImage (using CIGaussianBlur), and then use CIBlendWithMask to blend them together.

The inputs of CIBlendWithMask are the input image (the blurred image), the input background image (the unblurred image), and the mask image (the shape you want). The output is the image you desire.